# Change default marker for an image in GMaps API v3

Tags: google-maps

I'm trying to adapt code (google maps window with a sidebar) I found at http://koti.mbnet.fi/ojalesa/boundsbox/makemarker_sidebar.htm for a personal blog .

What I want is to change the default marker for an image (always the same).
All my attempts to recode have failed. Image is in folder images (images/monument.gif); I don't have for the moment an absolute URL.

I have tried to follow the API documentation and searching on Google, but no luck.

```
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var markerBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
var markerArray = [];

function makeMarker(options){
var pushPin = new google.maps.Marker({map:map});
pushPin.setOptions(options);
google.maps.event.addListener(pushPin, "click", function(){
infoWindow.setOptions(options);
infoWindow.open(map, pushPin);
if(this.sidebarButton)this.sidebarButton.button.focus();
});
var idleIcon = pushPin.getIcon();
if(options.sidebarItem){
pushPin.sidebarButton = new SidebarItem(pushPin, options);
pushPin.sidebarButton.addIn("sidebar");
}
markerBounds.extend(options.position);
markerArray.push(pushPin);
return pushPin;
}

google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(){
infoWindow.close();
});
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want the marker to be your GIF image instead of the default pushpin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var markerBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
var markerArray = [];

function makeMarker(options) {

    var pushPin = new google.maps.Marker({
        icon: 'images/monument.gif',
        map: map
    });

    pushPin.setOptions(options);

    google.maps.event.addListener(pushPin, "click", function() {
        infoWindow.setOptions(options);
        infoWindow.open(map, pushPin);
        if (this.sidebarButton) this.sidebarButton.button.focus();
    });

    if (options.sidebarItem) {
        pushPin.sidebarButton = new SidebarItem(pushPin, options);
        pushPin.sidebarButton.addIn("sidebar");
    }

    markerBounds.extend(options.position);
    markerArray.push(pushPin);
    return pushPin;
}

google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function() {
    infoWindow.close();
});
```

The only changes are the "icon" property in the MarkerOptions and and I removed the getIcon() call.

Comment: Ryan, thank you! It works! It's a very similar solution to one I tried. But maybe my syntax was not correct. I can't mark the answer as useful because I don't have enough reputation, but it's really useful for me.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `makeMarker()`, include `icon:"images/monument.gif"` in the options property list like this:

```
myPushPin = makeMarker({icon:"images/monument.gif", anotherOption:"anotherOptionValue"});
```

Comment: He wants the icon to be the default, having to pass the url with every creation doesn't reflect that.

Comment: Yes, if he wants all the icons to be monument.gif, your solution is the way to go.  I thought he only wanted it to appear in one place. Upon re-reading the question (which I edited, so you think I would have understood it), you appear to be correct.